# Python function with a unassigned variable

Tags: python, function, web, flask

I'm currently working on a flask and python app: https://getanumber.herokuapp.com/

When you click on generate without value, an Internal Server Error appears.

I would like to print a message when this happen. Here what I got so far with None value but it doesn't work:

```
def RandomNumberGenerator():
    import random
    Min = request.form['Min']
    Max = request.form['Max']
    xMin = int(Min)
    xMax = int(Max)
    if xMin > xMax:
        return "Min value can not be higher than max value"
    elif xMin is None:
        return "Precise the min value"
    elif xMax is None:
        return "Precise the max value"
    else:
        return str(random.randint(xMin, xMax))
```

BR

Comment: What happens when you do `int('')` ?

Comment: int(' ') convert the string I get from the html form to a integer

Comment: I know what `int` does. The question is what happens when you pass `int` an empty string.

Comment: Try copying exactly what he wrote into a Python interpreter and running it to see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner, I don't understand what i'm supposed to do with the `int(' ')` ...

Comment: I think you sould first activate debug mode for your flask application e then try to see more in depth what is going there. If you still can't find the solution, come back again with more information about the problem, because I'm sure it involves more than just the code you showed us. Here's the flask doc link (search for Debug Mode section): http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DeepSpace alludes to in his comment, you always need to check that user input are in order (generally referred to as input sanitizing).

```
try:
    Min = int(request.form['Min'])
    Max = int(request.form['Max'])
except ValueError as e:
    # Whatever you want to do if you got something other than a number.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't solve the problem. Maybe my Internal Server Error message is related to another issue.

Comment: I think you should experiment with your code in the Python interpreter for a bit until you're sure how it works. It seems like any error in your code will result in an Internal Server Error, which makes it difficult for you to debug. (Of course, that means that you can't use `request.form`, but you can work around that.)